# Do a vlookup on xml payload using Groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

I am new to coding and I would appreciate if anyone can help me with the below requirement.
I need to loop though the incoming payload comparing the userid with the manager Id's so that I can identify if an user is an employee or a manager.

Thanks.
Roy

Incoming Payload

```
<Employee>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>AAAAA</Userid>
      <ManagerID>XXXX</ManagerID>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>BBBBB</Userid>
      <ManagerID>YYYY</ManagerID>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>CCCC</Userid>
      <ManagerID>ZZZZ</ManagerID>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>XXXX</Userid>
      <ManagerID>YYYY</ManagerID>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>YYYY</Userid>
      <ManagerID>ZZZZ</ManagerID>
    </EmpJob>
</Employee>
```

Desired output.

```
<Employee>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>AAAAA</Userid>
      <ManagerID>XXXX</ManagerID>
      <Usertype>Employee</Usertype>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>BBBBB</Userid>
      <ManagerID>YYYY</ManagerID>
      <Usertype>Employee</Usertype>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>CCCCC</Userid>
      <ManagerID>ZZZZ</ManagerID>
      <Usertype>Employee</Usertype>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>XXXX</Userid>
      <ManagerID>YYYY</ManagerID>
      <Usertype>Manager</Usertype>
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
      <UseriD>YYYY</Userid>
      <ManagerID>ZZZZ</ManagerID>
      <Usertype>Manager</Usertype>
    </EmpJob>
</Employee>
```

I tried the below code but its returning usertype as "employee" for all the records.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body)
    
    xml.EmpJob.each { empJob ->
        def userID = empJob.UseriD.text()
        def managerID = empJob.ManagerID.text()
        def userType = userID == managerID ? "Manager" : "Employee"
    
        empJob.appendNode {
            Usertype(userType)
        }
    }    
    def transformedXml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)    
    message.setBody(transformedXml)    
    return message
}
```

Comment: What did try? What is working, what is not?

Comment: I tried the below code but its giving me usertype as "employee" for everyone

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking the current node's manager so unless they manage themself the user type will always be Employee. The following figures out all the managers up front, not sure this'd scale well with a massive data set but hopefully you get the idea.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body)

    def managers = xml.'**'.findAll{ node -> node.name() == 'ManagerID' }.unique()*.text()

    xml.EmpJob.each { empJob ->
        empJob.appendNode {
            Usertype(managers.contains(empJob.UseriD.text()) ? "Manager" : "Employee")
        }
    }
    def transformedXml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
    message.setBody(transformedXml)
    return message
}
```